# How can I create masking like this in AS3?

Tags: flash, mask, actionscript-3, transition

I've worked a little bit with masks in AS3 but I'm not sure how I can do this with masks.

I have two swf files that I have imported onto the Library as MC's with class names.

One of the files is the start image and the other is the end image. The transition is a slide transition from the start image to the end image. You can think of the transition like in [this example.](http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/masking/)

But is it possible to do a slide transition like this using two swf's and "slide transitioning" between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
Mask.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
Mask.graphics.drawRect(x, y, some.width, some.height);

Image.mask = Mask;
```

Was pretty simple actually, if you addChild Image and Mask, then mask will make Image transparent and you can move Mask around as you please.